# Using COUNT_RECURSIVE with a specified key name?

Tags: php, arrays, count

`count($arr['children'], COUNT_RECURSIVE);` to get the total number of keys inside the original children key, however I'm wanting to filter out all but the keys named 'children.' I'm unsure the count_recursive works like this.

```
$arr =  array (
    'id' => '81',
    'parent' => NULL,
    'children' =>
        array (
          0 =>
          array (
            'id' => '173',
            'parent' => '81',
          ),
          1 =>
          array (
            'id' => '84',
            'parent' => '81',
            'children' =>
            array (
              0 =>
              array (
                'id' => '85',
                'parent' => '84',
                'children' =>
                array (
                  0 =>
                  array (
                    'id' => '131',
                    'parent' => '85',
                    'children' =>
                    array (
                      0 =>
                      array (
                        'id' => '176',
                        'parent' => '131',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              1 =>
              array (
                'id' => '174',
                'parent' => '84',
              ),
              2 =>
              array (
                'id' => '175',
                'parent' => '84',
              ),
            ),
          ),
    ),
);

echo count($arr['children'], COUNT_RECURSIVE);
```

I'm trying to have it return 7, but because it's counting all keys, it returns 24. How could I do this?

Comment: I don't think there's anything built-in that does this, you'll have to write your own recursive function.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to filter out all key names that aren't named 'children'.

Comment: I don't think there's anything built-in that does that, either. I'm pretty sure there's nothing built-in that relates to what you're doing. Sorry, you're going to have to pretend you're a real programmer, not a hack who only knows how to copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

I've come a long way after the battle, but if you still want to copy and paste an algorithm that answers the question "how to recursively count the elements of this array that are themselves arrays but whose key is not 'children'", here is one that does the job and gives the expected "7" as the result:

```php
function countAllArraysButKey(array $array, int|string $but_key) : int
{
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (!is_array($value)) {
            continue;
        }
        $count += countAllArraysButKey($value, $but_key);
        if ($key !== $but_key) {
            $count ++;
        }
    }
    return $count;
}

echo 'count: ' . count($arr['children'], COUNT_RECURSIVE) . "\n";
echo 'countAllArraysButKey: ' . countAllArraysButKey($arr['children'], 'children') . "\n";
```

Have fun!